# Azure/WebMatrix web.config 500 Error

Tags: azure, webmatrix-2

I've tried to add a MIME type to the webmatrix web.config file to run in Azure:

```
<system.webServer>
     <staticContent>
         <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
     </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

But I get a 500 (Internal Server Error) when trying to load a json file.

The site works locally.

Is there something else in Azure I need to do?

(Edit:)

All I have in web.config is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
     <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
        <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
        <add invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" name="Microsoft® SQL Server®    Compact 4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
    </system.data>
<system.webServer>
  <staticContent>
<mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
</staticContent>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The bit without the MIME type was generated by webMatrix.

Error in console:

GET http://carlistings.azurewebsites.net/CarListings/data/cars.json?_dc=1364378861597&page=1&start=0&limit=25 500 (Internal Server Error)

**UPDATE**

The file doesn't change and is called by JavaScript from a Sencha Architect tutorial app.

```
{
"img" : "2004_Porsche_911_Carrera_type_997.jpg",
"manufacturer" : "Porsche",
"model" : "911",
"price" : 135000,
"wiki" : "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porsche_997",
"quality" : [{
    "name" : "overall",
    "rating" : 1
},{
    "name" : "mechanical",
    "rating" : 4
},{
    "name" : "powertrain",
    "rating" : 2
},{
    "name" : "body",
    "rating" : 4
},{
    "name" : "interior",
    "rating" : 3
},{
    "name" : "accessories",
    "rating" : 2
}]
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

I've noticed that running the app locally (where the app runs properly) the error log shows the cars.json file as application/json, whereas on the Azure server, it shows it as text/html.

It appears the Azure server is ignoring my web.config file with something else...

(I've enabled debugging in Azure but can't find a list of errors yet...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTTP 500 is coming from something else.

I added exactly what you did in a new empty WebSite and the result is as expected.

URL to test: http://jsonp.azurewebsites.net/demo.json

Here is a fiddler trace from the request:

```
GET http://jsonp.azurewebsites.net/demo.json HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: jsonp.azurewebsites.net
```

And the response is also as expected:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 30
Content-Type: application/json
Last-Modified: Wed, 27 Mar 2013 09:03:09 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "cc2c13e7c92ace1:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
.. aditional header omitted for readability
Date: Wed, 27 Mar 2013 09:03:52 GMT

{"title":"demo","count":10}
```

I suggest that you turn on all the possible logging and examine the error logs.
Most probably you define `system.webServer` twice, or something similar. Check out [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13079457/azure-website-debugging) on how to enable logging.

**UPDATE**

After updating the question it is apparent that `cars.json` is not real `static` file. So the question is a bit messed. What type of script are you executing inside this "file" ?

**UPDATE 2**

Here is your json: http://jsonp.azurewebsites.net/demo.json

Apparently you are having issue with rest of the website setup. As I said - turn on all the logging and check the real error messages.

Comment: All I have in my web.config file is:

Comment: Ok, so I found the error. I had left a mapping handler in the configure panel in Azure for .json. When I removed it, the site worked. So, I have accepted astaykov's answer as correct as it does work as described.