# Remote debugging Azure website a Visual Studio 2017 Project

Tags: azure, remote-debugging, visual-studio-2017

I recently installed Visual Studio 2017 and my problems began with remote debugging.

So, this is the message error.
[image]

And on Azure, they are lagging behind the official release of VS Remote Debugging for this VS  version.
[image]

Any idea on how to make this work?

Comment: I wouldn't use the words `forgot to implement`. I would rather use - `they are lagging behind the official release of VS`. So your option today is to use VS 2015 (or 2013/2012). And no - it will not work until `they` implement support for VS 2017 debugger. And IMO, this is not the type of question you should ask on StackOverflow.

Comment: tks man. I edited my question with your sugestion. So as you told, there's no way to remote debugging on 2017 right now? I didn't get why I shouldn't ask this on StackOverflow.

Comment: This is totally a developer question, and welcome on SO!

Comment: Since this was one of the top results when I was searching, I thought I'd add a link to my answer here in case it helps anyone else.  This is fully working now: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45706263/2869344

Answer (score 4):

If you use Cloud Explorer within Visual Studio 2017 to initiate the Remote Debugging it'll set the VS Version on the Web App correctly. Currently, the portal doesn't include UI to allow you to set 2017 as the version, but using the Cloud Explorer to initiate remote debugging will do it behind the scenes. We just need to wait for the Azure Portal to be updated and get caught up with VS.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2017 is now listed as a Remote Debugging Version in Azure.

There has however been some change on what is possible on Cloud Explorer. To access the 'Attach Debugger' option, you need to use the Server Explorer.